# gcloud app deploy crashes with "Unable to assign value to attribute 'timezone'" on Cloud SDK version 297.0.0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Using `gcloud app deploy` to deploy to App Engine will fail if cron.yaml or cron.xml contains timezone information, when run using Cloud SDK 297.0.0.

For example:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [/path/to/file/cron.yaml]
[INFO] GCLOUD: Unable to assign value 'America/New_York' to attribute 'timezone':
[INFO] GCLOUD: timezone 'America/New_York' is unknown
```

Answer (score 5):

The workaround is to downgrade to version 296.0.1 of the Cloud SDK. (Substitute 296.0.1 for VERSION below.)

- If you installed the SDK directly (outside of a package manager), you should use gcloud components to update: `gcloud components update --version VERSION`. This includes all installation mechanisms on this page (including the interactive installer, static versions, Windows installer, and Homebrew) but excludes the two following bullets.
- If you installed via the rapture repo for Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk=VERSION-0`
- If you installed via the rapture repo for RedHat/CentOS: `sudo yum downgrade google-cloud-sdk-VERSION`

If for any reason any of the above do not work, use the [download archive](https://storage.cloud.google.com/cloud-sdk-release) to manually download an older version, and install using http://cloud/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I wrote a ticket to the GCP support.
It seems that they are not well aware of the bug.